# Find all the polynomials $W (x)$ that meet the following two conditions:

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

$W(0)=2$ and $W(x_1+x_2)=W(x_1)+W(x_2)+2x_1x_2-2$

The first condition I know (theorem Bezout).
What does the second condition say to us?
How to solve this math problem?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far, and what thoughts do you have about the problem?

Comment: Can you, for instance, say anything about $W(x)$ for $x = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2$?
 That'd be a good place to start your investigations.

Comment: Hint: start with $W(x)=(x-1)^2+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have $W(0)=2$ we can write $W(x) = xQ(x)+2$ so

\begin{eqnarray}W'(x)&=&\lim _{h\to 0}{W(x+h)-W(x)\over h} \\&=&\lim _{h\to 0}{W(h) +2xh-2\over h}\\
&=&\lim _{h\to 0}{hQ(h)+2xh\over h} \\
&=& Q(0)+2x 
\end{eqnarray}

So $W(x) = 2+ax+x^2$ where $a=Q(0)$. Pluging this in to original equation we get:
$$ 2+a(x_1+x_2)+(x_1+x_2)^2 = 2+ax_1+x_1^2+2+ax_2+x_2^2 +2x_1x_2-2$$
which means that $W(x)$ works for any $a$.